# Circle to circle homotopic to the constant map?

Tags: general-topology, functions, algebraic-topology

How to prove that a continuous function, homotopic to the constant map $f:S^1\to S^1$  (a) has a fixed point and that (b) has a point $x$, such that $f$ maps $x$ to its antipodal point $-x$?

Comment: What are some of the approaches you've tried already?

Comment: Note that $0\notin S^1=\{\,z\in\mathbb C:|z|=1\,\}$. But parts of the problem statement seem to be unclear (so please check them again carefully): There are many $f\colon S^1\to S^1$ that are homotopic to the constant map -  and $x\mapsto -x$ is not among them

Comment: Well, indeed. Then how can I show that $f$ has a constant point? A constant point must satisfy $f(x)=x$. Let me try to re-write question. You are right, I ve not written it down well.

Comment: A typical trick s to assume that $f(x)\ne x$ for all $x$ and then consider $x\mapsto \frac{f(x)-x}{|f(x)-x|}$

Comment: I have re-written the question. I still do not see how your last comment satisfies my question!

Comment: What is $x$ in part (b)?

Comment: $x$ is mapped to $-x$ if this is what you are asking

Comment: Are you asking for the existence of some $x$ such that $f(x)=-x$ or that $f(x)=-x$ for all $x$?

Comment: Well, the question says: Prove that for $f:S^1\to S^1$ homotopic to the constant map, $f$ maps a random point $x$ to $-x$...

Comment: I believe the right phrasing would be "maps _some_ $x$ to it's antipodal point"

Comment: Arthur you are right. This is what I meant. I mixed the translation spanish to english. I still do not see though how such $f$ can satisfy a) and b).

Comment: Are you sure the question doesn't ask "Show, using part a, that the map $f\colon x\mapsto -x$ is not homotopic to a constant map."? Because that does indeed follow from part a by contradiction.

Comment: Yes! I am sure! It says a) prove that $f$ has a constant point and b) that $f$ maps some point $x$ to its antipodal $-x$!

Comment: Looks like there is another mistranslation. Probably your task is to prove that $f$ has a *fixed* point, i.e. there exists a point $a$ such that $f(a)=a$. And also (As Arthur observed) that there exists another point $b$ such that $f(b)=-b$.

Comment: Ok, I will ask the tutor and will write back. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8):

For the first part, let $i\colon S^1\to D^2$ be the inclusion of the circle into the unit disk and, since $f$ is null-homotopic, let $\tilde{f}\colon D^2\to S^1$ be an extension of $f$ to the whole disk (which exists). Since $f$ has no fixed points, and the image of $\tilde{f}$ lies within $S^1$, what can we say about $i\circ \tilde{f}\colon D^2\to D^2$ and what theorem about maps on disks does this contradict?

For the second part, just prove that the composition of a nullhomotopic map with the map which rotates the circle by $\pi$ is also nullhomotopic (hint: rotation is homotopic to the identity and if $f\simeq f'$ and $g\simeq g'$ then $f\circ g\simeq f'\circ g'$), and then use part a.

Comment: To get the extension do you apply some generalisation to $\mathbb R^2$ of Tietze's extension theorem?

Comment: @RudytheReindeer Usually the first thing you prove in an alegbraic topology class is that a null-homotopic map $S^1\to X$ can be extended to a map $D^2\to X$. This is also a sufficient condition for the map to be null-homotopic. Basically, just clue one end of the mapping cylinder, given by the homotopy one the 'constant end'. This 'mapping cone' can then be mapped to the disk by flattening it in the obvious way.

Comment: Ah, great, I understand. I think I can write the proof. Thank you very much for your comment!

Answer (score 7):

**Lemma**: Show that if $A$ is a retract of $B^2$, then every continuous map $f : A \to A$ has a fixed point.

**Proof**: Suppose that $A$ is a retract of $B^2$, then by definition there exists a continuous map $r : B^2 \to A$ such that $r(a) = a$ for all $a \in A$. Let $f : A \to A$ be an arbitrary continuous map. Define $g  : B^2 \to B^2$ by $g = j \circ f \circ r$ where $j : A \to B^2$ is the inclusion map. By the Brouwer fixed-point theorem for the disk, there exists $x \in B^2$ such that $g(x) = x$. But notice that $g(x) = j(f(r(x))) = f(r(x)) = x$ which means that $x \in A$ since $x \in \operatorname{Im}(f) \subseteq A$. Since $r$ is a retraction of $B^2$ onto $A$, $r(x) = x$ and hence $f(r(x)) = f(x) = x$. Conclude that $f$ has a fixed point.

**Theorem**: Show that if $h : S^1 \to S^1$ is nulhomotopic, then $h$ has a fixed point and $h$ maps some point $x$ to its antipode $-x$.

**Proof**: Since $h : S^1 \to S^1$ is nulhomotopic there exists a continuous extension $k : B^2 \to S^1$ of $h$ into $B^2$. Define $g : B^2 \to B^2$ by $g = j \circ k$ where $j : S^1 \to B^2$ is the inclusion map. $g$ is continuous, so by the fixed point theorem, there exists a fixed point $x \in B^2$ such that $g(x) = x$. But notice that $x = g(x) = j(k(x)) = k(x) \in S^1$ so $x \in S^1$ and hence $k(x) = h(x) = x$ and thus $h$ has a fixed point.

Define $\alpha : S^1 \to S^1$ by $\alpha(x) = -x$. By hypothesis, $h$ is nulhomotopic, so there exists $c \in S^1$ such that $h$ is homotopic to $e_c$. In particular, there exists a homotopy $F : S^1 \times I \to S^1$ such that $F(s, 0) = h(s)$ and $F(s, 1) = e_c(s) = c$. Since $\alpha$ is continuous, then $\alpha \circ F$ is a homotopy between $\alpha \circ h$ and $\alpha \circ e_c = e_{-c}$. Hence $\alpha \circ h$ is nulhomotopic. By previous discussion, there exists a fixed point $x$ such that $\alpha(h(x)) = -h(x) = x$. Multiply both sides by -1 and we get $h(x) = -x$. Conclude that $h$ maps some point $x$ to its antipode $-x$.

Answer (score 0):

Munkres (Topology(2nd ed)) has the following theorem (Theorem 55.5)

> Given a non-vanishing vector field $\tilde{f}:\mathbb{D}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2\setminus \{0\}$, there are points on $S^1$ where it respectively points directly inwards and outwards, *i.e*, $\exists s_1 \in S^1, \ \exists s_2 \in S^1,$  $\tilde{f}(s_1) = t_1s_1, \ \tilde{f}(s_2) = - t_2s_2; \ t_1, t_2 > 0$.

The statement in question is actually equivalent to this.

> $(\Rightarrow)$   if $f:S^1 \rightarrow S^1$ is *nullhomotopic*, $f$ can  be extended to a *continuous map* $\tilde{f}:\mathbb{D}^2 \rightarrow S^1 \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0\}$.
>   So, $\exists s_1 \in S^1, \ \exists s_2 \in S^1,$  $f(s_1) = t_1s_1, \ f(s_2) = - t_2s_2; \ t_1, t_2 > 0$.
>   But, $f(S^1) \subset S^1$ $\Longrightarrow$ $(f(s_1) = t_1 s_1 \in S^1 \Rightarrow t_1 =1)\wedge(f(s_2) = -t_2 s_2 \in S^1 \Rightarrow t_2 =1)$.
>   $\Longrightarrow$ $f(s_1) = s_1$; $f(s_2) = - s_2$.   $\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \blacksquare$
>
> $(\Leftarrow)$ Given $\tilde{f}:\mathbb{D}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2\setminus \{0\}$, we describe $\tilde{g}:\mathbb{D}^2 \rightarrow S^1$ as $\tilde{g} = \frac{\tilde{f}}{\parallel \tilde{f} \parallel}$ .
>   Then, $\tilde{g}|_{S^1}:S^1 \rightarrow S^1$ is nullhomotopic. $\Longrightarrow$ $\exists s_1,s_2 \in S^1, \ \ \ \tilde{g}(s_1)=s_1; \ \tilde{g}(s_2) = s_2$.
>   $\Longrightarrow$ $\tilde{f}(s_1)= \parallel \tilde{f}(s_1) \parallel s_1, \ \parallel\tilde{f}(s_1)\parallel > 0; \ \ \ \ \  \tilde{f}(s_2) = - \parallel \tilde{f}(s_2) \parallel s_2, \ \parallel \tilde{f}(s_2) \parallel>0$. $\ \ \ \ \blacksquare$

Munkres actually goes on to use the aforesaid theorem to prove *Brouwer's fixed point theorem*, which I believe all other proofs have used.

Answer (score 0):

for a different, very short proof: work in $\mathbb C$ and use winding numbers.

with $\gamma(t)=\exp\big(2\pi i \cdot t\big)$ for $t\in[0,1]$ you have
$n\big(f\circ\gamma, 0\big)=0$  since $f\circ \gamma$ is null-homotopic and
with the inversion map $h:z\mapsto z^{-1}$, consider the curve $\sigma$ given by $\sigma(t) := \big(h\circ \gamma(t)\big) \cdot \big(f\circ\gamma(t)\big)$
$\implies n\big(\sigma,0\big)=n\big(h\circ\gamma, 0\big)+n\big(f\circ\gamma, 0\big)=-1+0=-1\neq 0$
$\implies$the image of $\sigma$ is all of the unit circle, and in particular $1=\sigma(t')$ for some $t'\in [0,1]$
i.e. $\frac{1}{\gamma(t')}\cdot f\big(\gamma(t')\big)=1\implies f\big(\gamma(t')\big)=\gamma(t')$, so $f$ has a fixed point.